# Using wp_add_inline_style Inside a Template File

Tags: theme-development, templates, wp-enqueue-style

I'm trying to figure out how to get `wp_add_inline_style` to work inside a template file.

The code I'm using is this:

```
function custom_css() {

    $output = '.some-class { background: #000; }';

    if ( ! empty( $output ) ) {
        wp_add_inline_style( 'themename-style', $output );
    }

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_css' );
```

I can get it working perfectly if I add the code inside the `functions.php`.

However, I've created a template (`template-page-slider.php`). This template is the same as `page.php`, but, it has a custom slider built in.

I want users to be able to style the slider different for each page the template is used. I figured `wp_add_inline_style` would be the best way to go about this but I can't get `wp_add_inline_style` to work inside a template file.

Is anyone aware of any specific reason why `wp_add_inline_style` doesn't work inside template files?

Comment: Where do you put that function call in template file? PS. Template files should contain only presentation code, no logic should be placed in there...

Comment: I have a slider.php file included into the template-page-slider.php.

The above code is actually in the slider.php file.

Comment: And where is that slider.php file included exactly? Before or after wp_head call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conceptually [`wp_add_inline_style`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_style/) adds some lines as if they were concatenated to a style file. This means that your setup will only work if you are adding the inline style to a [style file loaded in the footer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/186065/how-to-load-css-in-the-footer/186066), because by the time you are calling `add_inline_style` in a template the header has already been assembled.

That said, this is really not a good idea. Functions need to be in the `functions.php` file to keep your code readable in the long term. If you want to enable users to add different styles per post, the best approach is to make a [custom field](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) for that, which you can read in time to enqueue it in the header.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Using the link you provided I've managed to get the styles to appear in the footer. However, this definitely isn't the approach I want to take.

The slider and all the controls are actually built with Advanced Custom Fields.

Could you provide me with a link to an example or explanation of how I could do this with custom fields?

Thanks again.

Comment: I don't know about ACF, but I'm sure there's a function to access those fields. You would build a function that you attach to the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook in which you access those fields to build the css, which you then add inline to a style file you have registered earlier.

Comment: I really don't know why I didn't think of this approach before. I already build custom styles for my customiser controls in a separate file and it works perfectly. What a great learning curve this has turned into today. Thanks for your time.